# Sorting and sub listing from lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have an array list with the following elements:

```
List<Record> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Record(3, "32"));
list.add(new Record(4, "42"));
list.add(new Record(1, "12"));
list.add(new Record(1, "11"));
list.add(new Record(2, "22"));
list.add(new Record(5, "52"));
list.add(new Record(5, "53"));
list.add(new Record(5, "51"));
```

**Record** is a simple POJO that has id and name

I want to do those to the list.

- Create a map like `Map<Integer, List<Record>>` that has a key is id and slimier key add as a list.I have done it as bellow.

  ```
  Map<Integer, List<Record>> map = list.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Record::getId, HashMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
  ```
- Now i want to sort the list by name and sub list to provided limit inside map

  ```
  map.forEach((k, v) -> v.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Record::getName)));    
  map.forEach((k, v) -> map.put(k, v.subList(0, Math.min(**limit**, v.size()))));
  ```

I have tried like above and looks like this is not a good way. Can anyone suggest a better way?

Answer (score 11):

You can use Java 8 [`Collectors.collectingAndThen()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) method:

```
Map<Integer, List<Record>> map = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Record::getId,
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.toList(),
            records -> records.stream()
                              .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Record::getName))
                              .limit(limit)
                              .collect(Collectors.toList()))));
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use `Collectors.collectingAndThen`:

```
Map<Integer, List<Record>> result = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
         Record::getId,
         Collectors.collectingAndThen(
             Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new),
             v -> {
                 v.sort(Comparator.comparing(Record::getName));
                 return v.subList(0, Math.min(LIMIT, v.size()));
             })));
```

This solution avoids creating a new stream for each list group.

As pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48828897/1876620), by using `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)` we ensure that the list is mutable, so that we can later sort it in place.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
Map<Integer, List<Record>> map = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Record::getId,Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)));
map.values().forEach(l -> {
    list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Record::getName));
    l.subList(limit, l.size()).clear();
});
```

Using `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)` we ensure that the result list will be mutable. Then we sort the list in-place and remove the unnecessary values. Instead of building a sublist containing the elements we want (which would keep a reference to the complete list), we build a sublist of the element we do not want and `clear()` it, to remove those element from the original list efficiently.

You may also write it as a single statement:

```
    Map<Integer, List<Record>> map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Record::getId,
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new),
                l -> {
                    list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Record::getName));
                    l.subList(limit, l.size()).clear();
                    l.trimToSize();
                    return l;
                })));
```

as a bonus, I also added `l.trimToSize();` which directs the `ArrayList` to use a smaller array if the preceding `.subList(limit, l.size()).clear()` removed a lot of elements. Since this may imply a copy operation, it’s a trade-off between CPU time and memory here. So if the result is only use for a rather short time afterwards, you would not use `trimToSize()`.

---

The operation becomes even simpler (and potentially more efficient) when you use [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex):

```
Map<Integer, List<Record>> map = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Record::getId,
             MoreCollectors.least(Comparator.comparing(Record::getName), limit)));
```

Comment: I'm not so sure about clearing the complement list and even less about trimming it. I think it depends on memory usage VS garbage collection cycles. Sometimes you may want to use as little memory as possible, but sometimes you might want to keep latency as low as possible. In this latter case you might want to measure carefully and avoid the GC run if you really don't need it. But I guess this is all theory and that it all depends on each specific case and usage scenario.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner when someone is caring about performance and memory usage then they should consider returning back to normal `for` loops and not the `StreamAPI`

Comment: @Lino Good point! :D However, while streams are slower than traditional for loops, they usually are very low latency. It's not the same to improve for performance than for low latency...

Comment: @ Federico Peralta Schaffner I already made it clear in my answer that it is a trade-off. I you are going to keep the result for a longer time, you do not want to keep a `subList` which is just a wrapper around the original list, which is not only holding a longer array, but references to all the collected elements (`Record` instances), which are not visible anymore, but can not get garbage collected. Such a behavior can be considered a memory leak. But yes, trimming is not so important. I added the StreamEx variant, which has the advantage of not collecting excess elements in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

```
list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
          Record::getId,
          Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                   Collectors.toList(),
                   x -> x.stream()
                         .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Record::getName))
                         .limit(limit)
                         .collect(Collectors.toList()))));
```

Comment: I don't know why, but I've seen you're collecting quite a bunch of negative votes lately. I really don't understand the 2 negatives for this answer, but I think you're up to something... :)

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I stopped caring to be honest... unless they come with constructive comments, I really don't care

Comment: @Eugene I downvoted, I thought it would not compile, but it's correct +1

Answer (score 1):

You could just sort *before* collecting the items in a Map. For the limiting bit, you can use `collectingAndThen` to post-process the list and `stream.limit` it.

```
Map<Integer, List<Record>> map = list.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Record::getName))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Record::getId, 
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), 
                        l -> l.stream().limit(limit).collect(Collectors.toList()))));
```

With `limit = 2`, this results in

```
{1=[Record(id=1, name=11), Record(id=1, name=12)], 
 2=[Record(id=2, name=22)], 
 3=[Record(id=3, name=32)], 
 4=[Record(id=4, name=42)], 
 5=[Record(id=5, name=51), Record(id=5, name=52)]}
```